# How to protect APIs of external PHP web application with IdentityServer?

Tags: identityserver4

I've a PHP application. I wish to centralize AA on IdentityServer. How to protect APIs of external PHP web application?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.
1. Configure your Apis to trust the Identity server( not sure any identity server library available for this to use in PHP. You have to check)

2. Identity server any way uses JWT token validation so you can use any JWT token validation library in your PHP api, decrypt the token using identity server cert( you can get cert url from identity server disco document) and validate the token parameters